# Finding a basis for $\text{span}\{x^{-2} - x, 2 - x^{-1}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

I need to find a basis for $V = \text{span}\{x^{-2} - x, 2 - x^{-1}\}$. Clearly $x^{-2} - x$ and $2-x^{-1}$ are linearly independent. So would it suffice to say that a basis for $\text{span}\{x^{-2} - x, 2 - x^{-1}\}$ is the set $$W = \{x^{-2} - x, 2 - x^{-1}\}?$$

I assume this because I know that the span of a set $S$ of vectors from a vector space $X$ is the set of all linear combinations of $S$. This seems to imply to me that $T = \{x,1,x^{-1},x^{-2}\}$ is not a basis because a vector from $V$ is of the form $$a(x^{-2} - x) + b(2 - x^{-1}) = ax^{-2} - ax + 2b - bx^{-1}.$$ So for example, $x^{-2} - 3x + 6 - 9x^{-1} \not \in V$ because the coefficients for say $x^{-2}$ and $x$ are not the same.

Comment: Yes, that is fine.  There are many different bases that you can use.  Some are more useful or interesting than others.  For example, we give special importance to *orthonormal bases* (with respect to a specific inner product) that we can find via the Gram-Schmidt process.  Otherwise, any linearly independent set of vectors that span a space can be a basis for said space (regardless how "nice" they look otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct -- a linearly independent set is always a basis for its span.

Your $T$ is not a basis, because it spans *too much*; for example $x$ itself is not in $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the set $S = \{x^{-2} - x, 2 - x^{-1}\}$ is linearly independent, and you require to find a basis for it.... but then the definition of a basis is a set that spans $S$ and is linearly independent.... so $S$ is already a basis for $span(S)$

Also you know that $T$ is not a basis for $S$, since $span(S)$ is already proven to have dimension of 2.. thus if $T$ were a basis this would contradict the theorem that all bases have the same cardinality.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces